# C++ error: "Array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer"

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I am getting the following C++ error:

```
array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer
```

From this line of C++

```
int cipher[Array_size][Array_size] = 0;
```

What is the problem here? What does the error mean? Below is the full code:

```
string decryption(string todecrypt)
{
    int cipher[Array_size][Array_size] = 0;
    string ciphercode = todecrypt.substr(0,3);
    todecrypt.erase(0,3);
    decodecipher(ciphercode,cipher);
    string decrypted = "";
    while(todecrypt.length()>0)
    {
        string unit_decrypt = todecrypt.substr(0,Array_size);
        todecrypt.erase(0,Array_size);
        int tomultiply[Array_size]=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Array_size; i++)
        {
            tomultiply[i] = int(unit_encrypt.substr(0,1));
            unit_encrypt.erase(0,1);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Array_size; i++)
        {
            int resultchar = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<Array_size; j++)
            {
                resultchar += tomultiply[j]*cipher[i][j]; 
            }
            decrypted += char((resultchar%229)-26);
        }
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The syntax to statically initialize an array uses curly braces, like this:

```
int array[10] = { 0 };
```

This will zero-initialize the array.

For multi-dimensional arrays, you need nested curly braces, like this:

```
int cipher[Array_size][Array_size]= { { 0 } };
```

Note that `Array_size` must be a compile-time constant for this to work.  If `Array_size` is not known at compile-time, you must use dynamic initialization.  (Preferably, an `std::vector`).

Comment: You can use just one set of curly braces (there are complicated rules for when braces can be omitted), but it's clearer to use nested braces.

Comment: Also the `0` is redundant

Answer (score 7):

You cannot initialize an array to '0' like that

```
int cipher[Array_size][Array_size]=0;
```

You can either initialize all the values in the array as you declare it like this:

```
// When using different values
int a[3] = {10,20,30};

// When using the same value for all members
int a[3] = {0};

// When using same value for all members in a 2D array
int a[Array_size][Array_size] = { { 0 } };
```

Or you need to initialize the values after declaration. If you want to initialize all values to 0 for example, you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array_size; i++ ) {
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[3] = {1};` will not initialize the same value for all members. Only the first element will be 1, the rest will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize arrays like this:

```
int cipher[Array_size][Array_size]=0;
```

The syntax for 2D arrays is:

```
int cipher[Array_size][Array_size]={{0}};
```

Note the curly braces on the right hand side of the initialization statement.

for 1D arrays:

```
int tomultiply[Array_size]={0};
```