# Set the absolute path with a variable on Linux using libcurl in C++

Tags: c++, linux, libcurl

How can i set the absolute path in libcurl on Linux, using a variable?

Here's an example code:

```
   }
    string absolute_path = "/home/user_name";
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    const char *url = "http://google.com";
    const char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = absolute_path;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

But the compiler returns this error:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you for your attention!

Comment: The line `const char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = absolute_path;` is definitely incorrect. Actually, you don't need `outfilename` variable. Use `absolute_path.c_str()` in `fopen()`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329324/c-error-array-must-be-initialized-with-a-brace-enclosed-initializer

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: I have solved my problem with user3159253's reply.

Comment: @user3159253 Why haven't You posted it as an answer?

Comment: I think It's too trivial to be the real answer, just a suggestion. Glad to hear that it helped though

Answer (score 1):

Use the `c_str()` [method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) of `std::string` type

e.g.

`const char* outfilename= absolute_path.c_str();`

P.S. Do you have an objective reason to declare the const char array ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i already try it but the compiler returns the same error. Now, i'm using directly the method fopen() as user3159253 told me, and it works.
P.S: I made a mistake, i have declared the variable as const char array because I was experiencing (for example. i had to declare const char *url as a const char to using a variable!

Comment: A simple example like this `std::string path = "myValue"; const char* src = path.c_str();` should never fail. Obviously you had another issue